# Breadcrumbs and cart display under navbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, cart, breadcrumbs

I would like to add two elements under my navbar. On the right side the cart of which you can see the content by clicking on it and on the other side, the breadcrumbs both aligned on a same row. [cf. pic related](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uDKc.png)

The whole thing would be dynamic also. I spent the whole day trying to find solutions without success. What would be the best way to do it? Flex display?

Thank you in advance for your help. Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.breadcrumbs ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item-left {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 50%;
}

.flex-item-right {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 50%;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a one column-layout instead of two-column layout */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item-left">
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-right">
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Cart</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <span>Cart item</span>  
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? you want to add 2 more icons to the right side of your cart like this? ```[CART][ITEM2][ITEM3]```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Salman Malik. I would like that when you click on the "cart" button, the products the cart display. So on the left side you would have the breadcrumbs and on the right side, the cart button on which you can see the products.

Comment: Sorry, I am lost and don't know who I am talking to in this website. The code here is perfectly fine: https://codepen.io/Lmonk72/pen/xxWGYXE. Now I am wondering how to center the cart button and the breadcrumbs when the screen size is less than 800px as shown in this picture: https://imgur.com/a/zoaCeCE. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Okay, I replaced what you said in the code, but the cart button still remains on the right side and doesn't go to the center.

Comment: this might be due to   ```flex-direction: row;``` on your default ```.flex-container``` try removing this line from there as well and since flex are by default rows it won't impact anything.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to mind.

1. Use `margin: left` on the button to push it to the further point available.
2. Use `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1` on the breadcrumb bar so that it uses all the available space except for that used by your button.

Working Codepen [example here](https://codepen.io/Lmonk72/pen/xxWGYXE)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are already doing it correctly, you just have to replace the `<span>Cart Item</span>` with your actual items, as of the formatting you don't really need to use flex since every item will be block scoped `div` here's what you will have to do to generate the dynamic content:

```
<div class="flex-item-right">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Cart</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <?php
            foreach($items as $item) {
        ?>
           <div>
                <?php $item['name'].' '.$item['quantity'].'x'; ?>
           </div>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and similarly you can add the total amount and go to cart button after the loop ends.

### UPDATE

I think I got the question wrong, you want your cart button to go extreme right and let the right side take whole space, here's what you should do:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item-left flex-grow-1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-right">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Add ``flex-grow``` property to your stylesheet as:

```
.flex-grow-1 {
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

and change the existing styles:

```
.flex-item-left {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-item-right {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

### UPDATE <800px

Simply make your `.flex-container` block scoped and it will center automatically:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-container {
    display:block;
   }
```

### Working Code Snippet

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.breadcrumbs ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #3498DB;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item-left {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.flex-item-right {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  padding: 10px;
}
.flex-grow-1{
    flex-grow:1;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a one column-layout instead of two-column layout */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-container {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item-left flex-grow-1">
        <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item-right">
        <div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Cart</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <span>Cart item</span>  
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well since you are already using the media query you can simply remove the flex behaviour by removing ```flex-direction:column;``` and adding ```display:block``` to the ```flex-container{}``` of media query what this will do it simply make the divs blocked scope allowing them to appear above and below.